# Typescript does not know about Array.map

Tags: typescript

I suspect I have made a mistake, but I can't get the following to pass type checking. I end up with `Property 'map' does not exist for type 'Restos'`. I have set up the interface according to the TS tutorials, so it feels as though `map` is not included as default (I have `"target": "es6"` in tsconfig)

```
interface Resto {
    rname:String,
    qname:String,
    tel:String
}

interface Restos {
    [index:number]:Resto;
}

class MainController {
    headline: String;
    rnames: [String];

    constructor($http : ng.IHttpService) {
        this.headline = "hello world";

        $http.get('http://afbackend.herokuapp.com/api/restos')
        .success( (res:Restos) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.rnames = res.map(r => r.rname)
                              ^^^ 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In your interface for Restos where is the map method? Maybe just use Resto[] instead of Restos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing the compiler knows is true about `Restos` is that when you index it by a `number`, you get a `Resto`. Just because something has a numeric index signature doesn't mean it's an array (for example, the object `{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}` can be indexed by numbers to produce strings, but you can't call `.map` on it).

What you probably want to write is `type Restos = Array<Resto>` instead of the interface.

Comment: Cheers - I was making it too complex with `Interface`, `type` does it. And `type Restos = Resto[]` worked too. (Yes, I know [String] was wrong too). In my defence I would note that the `type` syntax is not mentioned on http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook